# how can i handle click events from chart.js in lighning components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, charts, chartjs, chart.js

My problem is i can't handle click events when i'm using chart.js library. It throws me a namespace error. I'm trying to update the chart when i click it on some bars for example. I don't know if it is Locker Service or what but i can't do it. Can anyone help me or show me the way to accomplish this? Thanks.

The error: Uncaught Error: Access denied: {"from":{"namespace":"c"}}

Chart.js click event handle on Helper:

```
drawBarChart: function(component) {
    var config = {
        type: "horizontalBar",
        data: {
            labels: component.get("v.Labels"),
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Quota",
                    data: component.get("v.data1"),
                    borderColor: "#17395C",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(23, 57, 92, 0.6)",
                    fill: false,
                    pointBackgroundColor: "#D43E1E",
                    pointBorderWidth: 4,
                    pointHoverRadius: 5,
                    pointRadius: 3,
                    bezierCurve: true,
                    pointHitRadius: 10
                },
                {
                    label: "Total revenue",
                    data: component.get("v.data2"),
                    borderColor: "#C24229",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(194, 66, 41, 0.6)",
                    fill: true,
                    pointBackgroundColor: "#D43E1E",
                    pointBorderWidth: 4,
                    pointHoverRadius: 5,
                    pointRadius: 3,
                    bezierCurve: true,
                    pointHitRadius: 10
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            onClick: function(event) {
                var elements = component.chart.getElementAtEvent(event);
                var labels = [];
                if (elements.length === 1) {
                    console.log(elements[0]._view.label);
                    labels.push(elements[0]._view.label);
                    component.set("v.Labels", labels);
                    component.chart.data.labels = component.get("v.Labels");
                    component.chart.data.datasets[0].data = [21000000];
                    component.chart.data.datasets[1].data = [10000000];
                    component.chart.update();
                }
            },
            legend: {
                position: "bottom",
                padding: 10
            },
            responsive: true,
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{ stacked: false }],
                yAxes: [{ stacked: false }]
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: component.get("v.Title")
            }
        }
    };
    return config;
}
```

Chart creation on Controller:

```
var ctx = component.find("Chart").getElement();
var config = helper.drawBarChart(component);
component.chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

Comment: Please provide the specific error message and a sample of your code. We don't have enough information to help you at this point.

Comment: @sfdcfox I've already updated my question. Can you help me?